# How can I change a media attachment URL/slug, so that I can use that slug for a page?

Tags: urls, media, slug

As in the title.

Yoast is now installed so that all media page URLs redirect to the image itself, but how can I change that slug for the image? It's currently using the slug I'd like to use for a page.